# Hardware noob trying to value some old components

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard

I've just dismantled an old computer that was gifted to me. Is there any value in these components? (maybe collectible)
I'm not into this type of market and I would like to sell them if possible. I would love if you can value them for me if you know how much. Just know that all this components have no original envelope

Here's the list:

- Sony MPF920
- GeForce GT 520 DDR3 1Gb
- Modem interno 56k Nilox
- ASUS Rampage Formula
- Netmos 9820cv
- 4x1Gb ddr2 hyperx
- Cavi 9 pin FireWire 400 + 2xUSB2.0
- Scheda audio Supreme FX2
- Manhattan dissiptore lga775
- 2xCavo hdd ASUS 34 pin
- 5.25 media dashboard
- ASUS DRW-2014L1T masterizzatore
- 5xCavo Sata 6.0 Gb
- Intel Core 2 duo e8500 S-spec SLAPK
- HDD 320gb Maxtor
- HDD Seagate 120gb
- HDD Seagate Barracuda 7200.10 300gb
- HDD Samsung HD103SI 1Tb

Thanks to everyone partecipating in advance

Comment: There's no money in 15-year-old computer parts. Just make sure the drives are securely erased & give it to a charity who can get it to someone who otherwise wouldn't be able to afford one.

Comment: Actually om asking Just beacuse more than one people was interested in buying some of these pieces. So i don't think there's no value at all

Comment: If you can sell bits, good luck to you. This, however is not the site for parts valuations [there is no site on Stack Exchange this would be on topic, sorry.]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic for this community. We are here to provide recommendations for what to buy, not what to sell.